# Example for one key and multiple values in groovy

Tags: list, dictionary, groovy

I am looking for an example how to store one key and multiple values example qualifications as below:

```
[name:'Test1',job:'QA',qualifications:['Selenium','Java']]

Map<String,String>=new HashMap<String,String>//not allowing multiple values.
```

Comment: Why not declare and instantiate your map as `Map<String,List<String>>`?

Comment: @ernest_k:I tried your solution this way:               Map<String,List<String>> empCollection= new HashMap<String,List<String>>()

empCollection.put('name','Test1');
empCollection.put('qualifications','QA');
empCollection.put('qualifications','Selenium');

println("emp collection is:"+empCollection); //qualification value  QA is replaced by Selenium.

Comment: Your first line of code _is_ the example.  Get rid of the generics - neither (dynamic) groovy nor the JVM itself cares much about them anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You need to know, that you are using a map containing entries of different key type. In your case, the most common key type for all values is `Object`, becuase `name` and `job` keys are of type `String`, while `qualifications` is of type `List<String>`. If you want to create such a map step by step (by specifying each key-value entry), you need to make sure that `qualifications` is a list. You can do it by assigning a list of predefined entries, or by assigning an empty list and then adding elements to it with `<<` operator. Consider the following example:

```
def expected = [name:'Test1',job:'QA',qualifications:['Selenium','Java']]

def emp = [:]
emp.name = "Test1"
emp.job = "QA"
emp.qualifications = []
emp.qualifications << "Selenium"
emp.qualifications << "Java"

assert emp == expected
```

In this example, we create an empty list and later we add values to. Alternatively, we could assign a list containing both values already.

```
def expected = [name:'Test1',job:'QA',qualifications:['Selenium','Java']]

def emp = [:]
emp.name = "Test1"
emp.job = "QA"
emp.qualifications = ["Selenium", "Java"]

assert emp == expected
```

Your example from comment did something different. Instead of adding an element to a list, it was overriding `emp.qualification` entry with a value of type `String`. This is why it stored only single the last assigned value.